# load string array dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, arrays

I currently want a 2D array (4,4) to look like this:

```
        outArr = new string[4, 4]
        {
            {"0","0","0","0" },
            {"0","0","0","0" },
            {"0","0","0","0" },
            {"0","0","0","0" }
        };
```

However, I'm unsure of how to do with in code where the array sizes could be dynamic at runtime (i.e. 3,5 or 10,10)

I found this example on how to create the array dynamically (for an int array):

```
        int[,] myArray=new int[(int)s[0],(int)s[2]];
        myArray[0, 0] = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(myArray[0, 0]);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

But I want to know how to create the elements "0" in my array dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var r = 7;
var c = 4;

var outArr = new string[r, c];

for (var i = 0; i < r; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < c; j++)
        outArr[i, j] = "0";
```

That gives me:

[image: outArr]